# Extracting particular executable from Yocto build files

Tags: yocto

I have a project that could be built with the Yocto build system to generate a full disk image. According to the [existing procedure](https://www.pelion.com/docs/device-management/current/connecting/linux-on-raspberry-pi-3.html), I can get only a full disk image that should be flashed on SD card.

And this does not suit my needs because I can't flash the image on the board. In my case, I need to build a certain project (that currently has a recipe) to an executable. (This project currently is a part of the full disk that is built with Yocto)

So I am wondering, is it possible to extract this executable (and the libraries that this executable depends on) from Yocto build files, so that I could copy and install it on the board? Which possibilities do I have to do this? Do I have some quick and dirty way to do this?

P.S: I heard something about that Yocto can provide a package for a certain project, that could be installed by the corresponding package manager on the board. On the board installed dpkg package manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *a* solution to add `tar.gz` to your [IMAGE_FSTYPE](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-IMAGE_FSTYPES).
After building the image, you can extract the executable you were looking for from the created archive.

Or you add the [output format](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-IMAGE_TYPES) you need for your target and install the full image.